# Managing android projects from command line

Tags: android, command-line, dex, dx

I am managing and running my android app from command line without using ant, I followed these steps:

- generate R.java
- compile R.java and all `.java` files in `src` to `.class` files
- assembling set of class files into `dex` file using the command below
  `dx --dex --verbose --output=./bin/classes.dex ./bin`

`.class` files are in bin directory.

But I'm getting the following errors in these steps:

```
java.lang.Runtime exception:.\bin file not found 
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main..run
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main
```

Due to this, I'm unable to create the `Classes.dex` file.

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

*[not using eclipse and ant only through command line]*

Comment: if I use any IDE means ..............i cant able to get to know abt the whole process............so that only just if it is command line ...........I get know abt each and every step by step process

Comment: thanx man,.......I got it worked...........it is due to the dx.bat file...........in dx.bat file there was
set javaOpts=  and i deleted it ....................it is due memory shortage......thanx,raj

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "manage your Android projects from command line", when you should use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build.

Ant's `build.xml` is a official standardized way to build Android projects. Ant scripts can do anything you may need to build your project.

If you want most modern build tools for Android, you can look at [Gradle for Android projects](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). Note: today it's still in alpha stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the **full path** instead of the **relative path**.

Also you must put the class files inside a directory named exactly like it's **package name**. for example for com.test.me.MyActivity you must use com/test/me/MyActivity.class

And since we are on the topic, remember that **dx** can only work with class files created using Java6 (or less) so if you are using java7 to compile your code, add **"source 1.6 target 1.6"** parameters to your command line.